# LDO voltage lower than expected

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a 3.3V LDO TLV755 connected to a FTDI chip FT2232HL. But I only get 0.9V at the output terminal. I am not entirely sure what the reasons of this could be. When the FTDI chip connected with a power supply the curernt reading is about 70mA. Is the LDO not suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Could you supply us with a schematic or diagram please. We need to see your point-to-point connections and component values in order to post an answer, or even to comment on what we see.

Comment: Maybe you need to start with actual schematics of your device, its power path. What is your input? Did you apply correct EN signal? What happens if you cut the wire between TLV755 and FTDI IC?

Comment: Schematic diagram?  What is the voltage at the input to the regulator? What is the full part number of the IC?

Comment: Page 23 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv755p.pdf) lists orderable device (part number) and device marking... Since ti.com offers a 0.9V version of the part, can you look at the marking on the top of the device and confirm it is a TLV755**33** ("AN" or "1FWF" or "1H3H") and not a TLV755**09** ("AX" or "1HDH")

Comment: @MarkU damn, I juts noticed that. Let me check the exact pn :( This is really dumb of me.

Comment: Added the schematic for clarity

Comment: @MarkU you were right, I had an incorrect part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 23 of the datasheet at http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv755p.pdf lists orderable device (part number) and device marking... Since ti.com offers a 0.9V version of the part, check the marking on the top of the device to verify it is a TLV75533 ("AN" or "1FWF" or "1H3H") and not a TLV75509 ("AX" or "1HDH").